# Google reCAPTCHA v2 Refused to load the script

Tags: recaptcha, content-security-policy

I try enable recapture on my website.
I followgin this tutorial https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display
After recapture integration I receive following error: 
[image]

Obviously it is problem with CSP.

I have tried return CSP header from my nginx server:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://www.gstatic.com";
```

but that doesn't help, it seems that  recapture reads CSP rules from another place...
With using Disable CSP Chrome extention everthing works ok as well on FireFox with CSP ignore warnings in console. What could the problem be?